# How to pause or delay all jobs on Horizon queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm fairly new when it comes to Horizon and Queues and I ran into this problem.

I'm using Horizon + Redis for my queues. The jobs in the queue need to connect to a remote service and fetches some data. That service has some connection limits (for eg. 5 requests per minute and X request per hour/day). Sometimes it can also be unavailable or down for maintenance.

Now, I can have a lot of these jobs in the queue (like 10k or even more). And after 5th request in a given minute (or what the actual limit is) all remaining hits will return false and I would just have to delay them.

Then, after the first job gets delayed, all the jobs that come after that one will also try to connect to the remote service, will also fail and it will get delayed. And this will actually delay the number jobs until the service can accept accept the connections again.

This creates two problems:

1. It delays a lot of jobs, that after 5 or 10 retries will fail in the end creating a mass of failed jobs.
2. It will make a number unnecessary connections to the service that I have already maxed out. Some services don't like that and will delay things even more...

It would be good that I can somehow pause all the jobs on a given queue, or somehow just take 5 jobs per minute. The worst solution is probably just sleep() for 25 seconds, but event hat won't work if there is more than one worker.

I have tried using redis throttling:

```
Redis::throttle('key')->allow(10)->every(60)->then(function () {
    // Job logic...
}, function () {
    // Could not obtain lock...

    return $this->release(10);
});
```

but either I did something wrong (key setup) or something, but after first 10 jobs are done in the minute others are just delayed with release(10) and I have the same problem as described above.

I'm sure that someone had an issue like this and I'm curious what's the right way to approach this.

Thanks for the help in advance!